# RequireJS Passing Dependencies

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Not sure if this has been asked already but I am just wondering if importing a dependency using RequireJS to one file and then importing that file to another means the second file has to import the same dependency as the first file.

example -

file A

```
define([
    'jquery'
],function($) {
    //jquery thing here
}
```

File B

```
define([
    'A'
],function(A) {
    // do some jquery thing here
}
```

or

```
define([
    'jquery','A'
],function($,A) {
    // do some jquery thing here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is good modularization practice to have each module list its own dependencies explicitly rather than silently depend on a module being loaded through an intermediary. So your module B should take the second form you suggested for it: `define(['jquery', 'A'], function ($, A) {...`.

Now, strictly speaking, you *could* have `B` only require `A` and you would be *able* to use jQuery in `B` without `B` having an explicitly dependency on jQuery. This is doable because jQuery, even when it is loaded as an AMD module, by default leaks `$` and `jQuery` into the global space just like it does when it is loaded outside RequireJS. However, it is not good practice. You should not rely on this though unless you have a substantial reason to do so and document it very verbosely.

Comment: Is that true, re:leaking `$`? (If so, TIL.)

Comment: Hmm.... why would I write something that I've not actually experienced? Look at the code of [jquery](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js) at the very end. There's a comment that points it out: "Expose jQuery and $ identifiers, even in AMD". jQuery has done this in AMD for years.

Comment: thanks for adding the information about jquery in your answer. This was an actual case that I found when editing code, and it is good to know that jquery is different than normal dependencies.

Comment: It's also the case of, for example, d3, html2canvas, dat.gui, three. js and others. Or it used to. Too many things would break if there weren't jQuery or $ in the global scope

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use the third option, because otherwise $ will be undefined in the module B. But this doesn't mean RequireJS will import jQuery twice internally, it will just pass you the $ variable.

```
define([
    'jquery','A'
],function($,A) {
    // $ was passed as a function argument.
}
```